# File not found with singular glob \.tmp\templateCacheHtml.js

Tags: javascript, npm, yeoman-generator-angular, gulp-inject

I am getting the following error when i build the file using `gulp build`. but `gulp serve` works fine without any errors. I am getting the error like

> (node:7144) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
>   rejection (rejection id: 1): Error: File not found with singular glob:
>   .tmp\templateCacheHtml.js
>       (node:7144) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are
>   not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit
>   code.
>       [12:36:51] 'build' errored after 26 ms
>       [12:36:51] Error: File not found with singular glob: .tmp\index.html

previously my project folder contains `bower_components` as `<dir>/bower_components/packages` now i changed to `node_modules/@bower_components/packages`. because i migrated to yarn.
My index.html file like as below, Anything need to changed in index.html?

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,src/client}) scripts/vendor.js -->
  <!-- inject:js -->
  <!-- js files will be automatically insert here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->

<!-- build:js({.tmp,src/client}) scripts/app.js -->
  <!-- inject:partials -->
  <!-- angular templates will be automatically converted in js and inserted here -->
  <!-- endinject -->
  <!-- endbuild -->
```

Can someone suggest me a solution for this?
Thanks,